# Different ItemDefinitionGroup for different ItemGroup

Tags: msbuild

I'm currently working using MSBuild, and in one of the vcxproj files, I'd like to have different ItemDefinitionGroup for different ItemGroup, without overriding each other, so that each ItemGroup has its own specific definition, e.g.

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Label="ItemDefGroupA">
    <CLCompile>
        <AdditionalOptions> /option_for_item_group_A</AdditionalOptions>
    </CLCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

<ItemGroup Label="ItemGroupA">
    <CLCompile Include="src\main.cpp" />
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <CLCompile>
        <AdditionalOptions> /option_for_item_group_B</AdditionalOptions>
    </CLCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

<ItemGroup Label="ItemGroupB">
    <CLCompile Include="src\main2.cpp" />
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Is this even possible?

Thank you very much in advance, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Label` attribute is ignored by MSBuild execution engine. The only place where it is used is by IDE code that needs to know a location inside project file to insert new entities, which happens if you modify your project in Visual Studio. The [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure.aspx) gives some information on how `Label`s are used by IDE.

So, what you are doing would not work. You only have one `CLCompile` item group, and your multiple item definition groups override each other. Whatever definition group is evaluated last, it wins. Note that the Item Definitions are evaluated first, after that Items are evaluated on next pass ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997067.aspx)).

One possible workaround for your scenario is to create couple of auxiliary groups, like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <GroupA Include="src\file1.cpp" />
    <GroupA Include="src\file2.cpp" />
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <GroupB Include="src\file3.cpp" />
    <GroupB Include="src\file4.cpp" />
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Then you initialize your CLCompile group from a combination of the two with different metadata values:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CLCompile Include="@(GroupA)">
        <AdditionalOptions> /option_for_item_group_A</AdditionalOptions>
    </CLCompile>
    <CLCompile Include="@(GroupB)">
        <AdditionalOptions> /option_for_item_group_B</AdditionalOptions>
    </CLCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks S.T. That's actually quite a clean workaround. I'll use it for my projects. Again, thanks for the swift reply and great solution.